# Wrapping in column in FPDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

I am generating a PDF with the help of FPDF library. It fetch the data from MYSQL databse.when the text size in any column is big it crosses the column and overlap with the text of next column. I want my text to be wrapped in that column only. When I tried using Multicell function the PDF was completely distorted. I have gone through the different post in this forum but I could not  achieve it Kindly help me to achieve this my code goes.

```
function viewTable()
    foreach($results as $result){
        $this->cell(75,10,$result->user,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(80,10,$result->affiliation,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(34,10,$result->type,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(30,10,$result->sampleid,1,0,'L');
    }
    $pdf = new mypdf();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
    $pdf->Header1();
    $pdf->headerTable();
    $pdf->viewTable();
    $pdf->footer();
    $pdf->output();
```

Comment: Your code has faults, so the brackets for the function are missing. Try to repair the code by editing your question. If you could also give some example text for the problematic cells that would be great.

Comment: @David I have edited and my code is working fine only problem with wrapping

Comment: The function `viewTable` never has any curly brackets, so where does it end?

Comment: also `$results` is not known in the function, it's a missing parameter for the function or where it's taken from?

Answer (score 0):

`fpdf` seems having very limited support for tables.
the function `cell()` is creating cells like in a table but there is no automatic resizing like in HTML.
An example can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537353/how-to-wrap-text-in-a-cell-by-increasing-the-height-of-the-cell-in-asp-with-fpdf).

So even if you manage restricting the visible cells in length you'll stumble about the issue that cells overlap and are hard to adjust.
What is missing is that a real table is calculating the measures of the cells new when content is added. This could be done by rendering the code twice, one in a virtual table that is just used to get some measures or amount of used lines if text is rendered after getting several line-breaks.

**So the short answer on your question is:** use another library, it doesn't matter if it's based on `fpdf` as long as it includes additional functionality according to your requirement(s).

Below first I write your code but corrected:

```
require('fpdf.php');

class mypdf extends FPDF
{
    public function viewTable($results)
    {
      foreach($results as $result){
        $this->cell(75,10,$result->user,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(80,10,$result->affiliation,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(34,10,$result->type,1,0,'L');
        $this->cell(30,10,$result->sampleid,1,0,'L');
        // add line break at the end of one data-set
        $this->Ln();
      }
    }

    //  ... other methods below ...

    public function Header1()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function headerTable()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function footer()
    {
        ...
    }

    private function calculateSomething()
    {
        // Here you can calculate something but you can't
        // call the function from outside with $pdf->calculateSomething()
    }

    protected function calculateSomethingElse()
    {
        // Here you can calculate something but you can't
        // call the function from outside with $pdf->calculateSomethingElse()
        // Nevertheless you could extend this class and call this function
        // from the extending class.
    }
}

    // some example data
    $results = [
      'user cell, user cell, user cell, user cell, user cell',
      'affiliation cell, affiliation cell, affiliation cell, affiliation cell',
      'type cell',
      'sampleid cell, sampleid cell'
    ]

    $pdf = new mypdf();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
    $pdf->Header1();
    $pdf->headerTable();
    $pdf->viewTable($results);
    $pdf->footer();
    $pdf->output();
```

Like in the linked answer probably you want to ad  a line-break at the end of each data-set (row):
`$pdf->Ln();`.
You even could calculate the length of the content and add line-breaks in the content by yourself.

But you could also try it with other functions like `write()` to get the desired behavior, just without further calculation you won't be able to display a proper table.

Comment: what is the meaning of other method mentioned in your code. Can u explain more about your code. Thanks for your reply

Comment: That means all methods I never added in the class still have to be filled in there if you created individual ones like `... function headerTable()` or `... function footer()`. You must have a class file where those methods are included. The word `method` is used for `function` in the context of a class, so if it's easier for you, just replace `method` by `function` or class-function.

Comment: the three dots, leading the word function like this `... function` I added because usually the visibilty of a method should be defined with one of the three words `public`, `protected` or `private`. As your methods are probably all public you could leave it like it is in my code in the answer without any keyword for visibility but it's a good style to add it. Also you can additionally define `private` or `protected` methods for class-internal calculations that are not accessible from outside the class.

Comment: I found this [external article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/226/top-5-best-open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-for-php) with some other libraries, perhaps it's helping you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply still could not get any thing.May I ask you to edit my code so that I can understand

Comment: Here you find a deeper explanation concerning visibility of properties and methods in classes: [PHP-Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)